# ebay FindingAPI how to find items specified within a given day range

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I am using this code portion to find all items which are in Auction type using ebay FindingAPI . Now I want to filter those items which have been started within a specified day (e.g: 2 days) . How can I add this preference??

Check this [link](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=gruen%20-sara%20-quartz%20-embassy%20-bob%20-robert%20-elephants%20-adidas&_sacat=0&_odkw=gruen%20-sara%20-quartz%20-embassy%20-bob%20-robert%20-elephants%20-adidas&LH_Auction=1&_ipg=50&_sadis=200&LH_SALE_CURRENCY=0&_ftrt=903&_oexkw=sara%20quartz%20embassy%20bob%20robert%20elephants%20adidas%5C&LH_Time=1&_ftrv=48&_LH_Time=1&_adv=1%5C%7C1&_sop=12&_osacat=0&_dmd=1&_okw=gruen%5C) and preference type . Here is the code portion :

```
IPaginationInput pagination = new PaginationInput();

pagination.entriesPerPageSpecified = true;
pagination.entriesPerPage = 100;
pagination.pageNumberSpecified = true;
pagination.pageNumber = curPage;
request.paginationInput = pagination;

ItemFilter if1 = new ItemFilter();
ItemFilter if2 = new ItemFilter();
if1.name = ItemFilterType.ListingType;
if1.value = new string[] { "Auction" };




ItemFilter[] ifa = new ItemFilter[1];
ifa[0] = if1;
request.itemFilter = ifa;

FindItemsByKeywordsResponse response = client.findItemsByKeywords(request);


foreach (var item in response.searchResult.item)
{

    tw.WriteLine(item.viewItemURL.ToString());
    links.Add(item.viewItemURL.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Dont think there is a filter for that. FilterType only has EndTimeFrom EndTimeTo not startTime http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/callref/types/ItemFilterType.html

Comment: Have you tried to use the `ModTimeFrom`-type? Sure, it takes all auctions that have changed status, but maybe you can filter down the auctions client-side when you have this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you roughly what you need. Set the two dates used to compare to whatever you want.

```
IPaginationInput pagination = new PaginationInput();

                    pagination.entriesPerPageSpecified = true;
                    pagination.entriesPerPage = 100;
                    pagination.pageNumberSpecified = true;
                    pagination.pageNumber = curPage;
                    request.paginationInput = pagination;

                    ItemFilter if1 = new ItemFilter();
                    ItemFilter if2 = new ItemFilter();
                    if1.name = ItemFilterType.ListingType;
                    if1.value = new string[] { "Auction" };




                    ItemFilter[] ifa = new ItemFilter[1];
                    ifa[0] = if1;
                    request.itemFilter = ifa;

                    FindItemsByKeywordsResponse response = client.findItemsByKeywords(request);


                    foreach (var item in response.searchResult.item)
                    {
                         // EDIT
                         if (item.listingInfo.startTime.CompareTo(DateTime.UtcNow) > -1) // -1 is earlyer; 0 is same; +1 is later then
                         {
                           if (item.listingInfo.startTime.CompareTo(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-2)) == -1 )
                           {
                               // You have an Item that was started between now and two days ago.
                               // Do something

                           }
                        }
                        // END EDIT

                        tw.WriteLine(item.viewItemURL.ToString());
                        links.Add(item.viewItemURL.ToString());
                    }
```